# PostgreSQL (Create Table)

Tags: postgresql, integer, numeric, create-table, sqldatatypes

I am trying to create a table.  One of the columns; "start_lng" meaning start longitude, includes a negative decimal number (-87.223655662). As I create my columns what kind of data type would this categorize as. I was going to use `INT` but then I realized that can only include whole numbers.  Then I thought about `NUMERIC` but I am confused on whether or not that can be negative or not.  I have attached my code below.  Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE may_2021 (
ride_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
rideable_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
started_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
ended_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
ride_length INTERVAL(1000) NOT NULL,
day_of_week INTEGER NOT NULL,
start_station_name TEXT,
start_station_id VARCHAR(75),
end_station_name TEXT,
end_station_id VARCHAR(75),
start_lat NUMERIC(15,15) NOT NULL,
start_lng NUMERIC(15,15) NOT NULL,
end_lat NUMERIC(15,15) NOT NULL,
end_lng NUMERIC(15,15) NOT NULL,
member_casual TEXT
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes ,numeric data type allows negative values .

Answer (score 1):

The correct data type for coordinates would be `double precision`.

The even more correct data type to represent `start_lat` and `start_lng` would be `point`.

But the best thing you can do if you want to use these coordinates inside the database would be to install the PostGIS extension and model it as a `geometry` or `geography`.